# What is the tafseer of Hadith H 10, Ch. 1, h 10 in Kitab al-Kafi?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, shiism

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

The Hadith **H 10, Ch. 1, h 10** in Kitab al-Kafi:

> Muhammad ibn Yahya has narrated from Ahmad ibn Muhammad from ibn
> Mahbub from ‘Abdallah ibn Sinan who has said the following.
> "I mentioned a person, who would overdo the deeds of his doing Wudu and
> prayer to Imam abu ‘Abdallah (a.s) and added that he is a man of good
> intelligence." The Imam (a.s) then said, ‘What kind of intelligence is
> it that allows him to obey Satan.’ I then asked the Imam, "How would
> he be considered as obeying Satan?" The Imam (a.s) said, "Ask him
> wherefrom this thing comes to him. He will certainly say, "It comes
> from Satan."

What is the tafseer (commentary) of this Hadith?

Comment: Is it a Hadith??.

Comment: Probably referring to there being some sort of waswasah that compels him to overdo those things.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have written the address of this hadith very briefly, it was very difficult for me to find the text and address of this hadith. But I found this hadith.(  al-Kafi  Book Volume 1 Page 12)
In this hadith, Imam Sadegh (as) is asked about "obsession in performing a person's ablution".
The interpretation of this hadith is as follows: Obsession and doubt are among the evil dangers that it instills in the hearts of the people, as peace, certainty and stability are the manifestations of God's mercy and instincts. Obsession makes what God has made difficult.
What is even more ridiculous is that some of these obsessive people invalidate the actions of all people and consider all people to be careless about religion.

Sheikh Ja'far Kashif al-Ghatta 'has said about some of these sins:

"The obsession that God commanded to be supplicated in Surah An-Nas is a state in man that prevents stability and confidence and is like madness and has different types and its source is the overcoming of delusion and anxiety of thought ... Obsession from It is a reprehensible attribute that has been forbidden by the intellect and the Shari'a, and although it is inherently ugly, it is the cause of great corruption.

https://hawzah.net/fa/Magazine/View/6442/7652/95806/%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%86